# jQuery datatables for non-tabular data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I like the [datatables plugin](https://datatables.net/) a lot for creating ad-hoc, combinable filters for structured data.

But there are often use cases where a table is just not the best form to present the data.

I'm aware that columns can be hidden in datatables so it won't look like a table anymore. But that doesn't make too much sense.

As datatables doesn't support non-tabular data, what alternatives are there?

I came across https://www.dynatable.com/ (project seems dead) and http://www.listjs.com (less feature-rich).

What tools (jQuery or vanilla JS) could be used for datatables-like filtering of non-tabular data?

Comment: I understand SO is not primarily for "which plugin can you recommend" questions; but where should they be put?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer ist list.js , https://github.com/javve/list.js

There are no official samples for multiple combined filters, but they are easily possible.